# Android vector drawable editor

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I'd like to modify existing Android drawable **vector** XML resource, but Android Studio let do it only in XML source.

Could you suggest a tool for "interactive" editing Android drawable XML?

Or may be there is a way to import such files to, say Incscape, or Adobe...

Comment: This question, like many others, should not be closed.

Answer (score 21):

Here is my IDEA plugin : [VectorPathTweaker](https://github.com/KnIfER/AndroidVectorPathTweaker)

With this you can easily translate, scale, flip and transpose **standard** android vector drawables.

[image: img]

For installation you need to search for 'VectorPathTweaker' on the plugin market.

tips: you can tweak the values by scrolling the mouse wheel.

Comment: I just installed it in Android Studio 3.6.2: amazing work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a amazing tool. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Not working for me, keeps adding commas everywhere so that the vector drawable is then invalid.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to figure out how to use this after installing.  In the vector file, select the path you want to modify and then open the right click menu and select "Tweak Vector Path".

Answer (score 1):

Is not really what you are asking but on latest version of Android Studio (3.2.1) you have a preview option for all the xml vectors. At this way, you can see the changes while editing the vector which can be very useful. You can find it on the right side of the Android Studio. Check at the screenshot I attach to you.[Preview of a vecotr drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51xFY.png)

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)